# Publish Google Slides to the Web (Specific Page)

Tags: html, google-slides

Is there a way to publish Google Slides to the web to open up to a specific page and NOT allow access to the other slides? For example, let's say I wanted to open up to a specific id or page number and prevent access to the clicking around on other slides. How would I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to do that without giving access to the other slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hide all other slides by right-clicking on those slides and selecting **Skip slide**, except the one slide you want the user to view.